# Overwriting a line in java txt file

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

So I have created this method which at the end displays the whole line because i am displaying the array after converting and editing it. So my Question is how can i know overwrite the array to the same line i grabbed it from. thanks in advance and here is my code.

```
       public void getData(String path, String accountNumber) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        System.out.println("Please Enter the Deposit amount That you would like to add.");

        Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);

         int add = sn.nextInt();

        String str;

        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (str.contains(accountNumber)) {
                String[] array = str.split(" ");
                int old = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
                int Sum= old + add;
                String Sumf = Integer.toString(Sum);
                array[3] = Sumf;

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(array[i]);}

                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }


}
```

i am using string accountNumber to grab the specific line that i need. after getting the line i am changing it to an array while splitting the index with         str.split(" "); . After that i know that i need to edit index number [3]. so i do so and then i put it back into the array. the final thing i need to do is to right the array back now.

Comment: after editing the array you want to convert the array to string again ??

Comment: so right now after editing it i am displaying it. then i wanna write it into the same line i grabbed it from. 

so lets say line 1 contains : a b c 3

then i grabbed it and created the array and my array now looks like: array[a,b,c,3]

then when i edit it i made it look like 

array[a,b,c,4] 

now i want line 1 to be : a b c 4

so i write the new array to its same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of the input from the file you are reading and write it back with the modified version.

```
public void getData(String path, String accountNumber) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        System.out.println("Please Enter the Deposit amount That you would like to add.");

        Scanner sn = new Scanner (System.in);

        int add = sn.nextInt();

        String line; // current line
        String input = ""; // overall input

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(accountNumber)) {
                String[] array = line.split(" ");
                int old = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
                int Sum= old + add;
                String Sumf = Integer.toString(Sum);
                array[3] = Sumf;

                // rebuild the 'line' string with the modified value
                line = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                    line+=array[i]+" ";
                line = line.substring(0,line.length()-1); // remove the final space
            }

            // add the 'line' string to the overall input
            input+=line+"\n";
        }

        // write the 'input' String with the replaced line OVER the same file
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        fileOut.write(input.getBytes());
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain what do you mean by what format is my input? also can you explain this line    " input+=str+"\n"; "   and why do we have \n. i know its a new line but why?

Comment: I just meant that I don't know what the text file that you're reading looks like exactly.
The new line is because when reading files the new line character sequence does not show up in the String but is necessary when writing the String back to the file.

Comment: so my file is %s %s %s %d and i am editing the digital at the end. 

also the input+=str+"\n"; specificaly input gives me an errorr says import jdk.nashorn.tools.ShellFunctions.input and when i do its still giving error

Comment: Try copying the latest version of the code because I made some minor changes. It is looking for jdk.nashorn.tools.ShellFunctions.input because it believes that the 'input' is a class rather than the variable. I actually forgot to declare/initialize it haha.

Comment: Thank you very much. mind commenting it so i can learn it more? at  least the bit you added. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how i understand the question that you have a file you will read it line by line and will make some changes and want to write it again at the same position. Create a new temp file and write the contents to the temp file, if changed write the changed result if not write it as it is.
And at last rename the temp to your original file name

Comment: but then i will be creating a new file every time. can i just edit that specific line in the same txt file that i grabbed it from?

Comment: it is easier if you don't doboth at the same time.  run through the entire file, make the changes and keep it read in Stringbuilder. Then if you need to, move the new file over the old one.
You never want to read and write to the same file at the same time. Your offsets within the file will shift everytime you make a write and the read cursor will not keep track of that.

Comment: its a bank so every time i need to write i need to enter a different account number and then close the file